# How do electrons keep moving when bare copper wires are rolled?

Tags: electricity, electrons

How do electrons keep moving when bare copper wires are rolled?

When someone strips the wires and coils the copper, does that not affect the communication between the devices, that is, the bits do not arrive corrupt?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are actually asking.

Comment: I mean a device eg (speaker) that has copper wires where electrons travel, if those wires are rolled to another copper wire that goes to a computer adapter. how electrons travel from one side to the other and go through the "disturbance" (coil) without changing the information. I imagine the sound will be all distorted.
How do you keep the information about copper undisturbed in it?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but the coiled wire in a speaker, and most electromagnets, is not actually stripped. It is usually coated with a very thin, often clear insulative coating, so they only look bare..

Comment: The poster's question was clear enough if one wanted to understand. I remember that I also wondered about this (ages ago). Sure, if one knows the answer and knows the technical jargon in English for this, it would be easier to write a clear question, but why should this be a requirement?

Answer (score 3):

You may not see the insulation. The copper wire in coils must be insulated (if there is no air gap), but that insulation is often a clear lacquer (historically shellac). For high temperatures etc, Kapton can be used as the insulating material.